# Windows Authentication for domain users in ASP.NET and IIS 7

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, iis

I want the domain users to be able to access my website without being prompted for their username and password. So far I have enabled Windows Authentication and disabled Anonymous Authentication for my website. Both in Visual Studio and IIS.

In Internet Explorer 11 (which is most important) it prompts the user and will not give access to domain users even when entered. In Chrome it prompts as well, but accepts the username and password.

How can I get rid of both the prompt and have Internet Explorer give access as well?

The following is also in my `Web.config`.

```
<system.web>
    <authentication mode="Windows"></authentication>
</system.web>
```

Comment: Hi, maybe is a bit late but here is an example :

https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/security/authenticating-users-with-windows-authentication-cs

Comment: Thank you. It turns out the `Negotiate` provider was the default one. Moving `NTLM` above `Negotiate` in the provider list both got rid of the popup and let users log in in IE. [Ref image(Imgur)](http://imgur.com/a/F1P7t)